# In Scrapy Why getting this Error not match the date format I Even read its documentation and I hope I am doing code same to the documentation

Tags: python, datetime, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

In Scrapy Why getting this Error not match the date format I Even read its documentation and I hope I am doing code same to the documentation

```
Published_Date = response.css('span[class="published-date-day"] ::text').get().strip().replace(",","").replace(".","")#Sept. 23, 2022 
    
Published_Date =  datetime.strptime(Published_Date, "%b %d %Y").date()
```

documentation link https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime

website link https://www.latimes.com/world-nation/story/2022-09-23/hong-kong-end-mandatory-covid-hotel-quarantine-travelers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you do:

```
published_date = response.xpath('//time[@class="published-date"]/@datetime').get().split('T')[0]
```

This way you obtain the date in ISO format.